For Qt translations: Is there a way to set the order for alternative translations for unfinished translations?
I have a large Qt application that supports 6 different languages. Unfortunately, many text phrases have not yet been translated. The base language in the source text is German. So if a translation is missing, the base language is used. Is there a way to specify an alternative language other than the base language for the various languages ​​and only switch to the actual base language if this is also missing.
For example, the language cz is used:
A translation is missing but there is an English translation. Then this should be used, if there is no English translation either, the base language (German) should be used.

First load the english translator and then the czech translator.

I don't know exactly how to do this correctly. So far by code uses first translator.load(lang) and then installTranslator(&translator). I've tried using translator.load(en) then translator.load(cz)  followed by installTranslator(&translator). But this have no effect.

I wrote that you should install two translators, not that you should install the same translator with two different qm files - this will and can't work.

OK, it now works as expected. Here is my code how to install two translators.
    const QString languageFilePrefix = ":/lang/resources/lang/MyApp_";
    const QList<QString> supportedLanguages({ "en","cs","pl","fr","pt"});

    QTranslator en_translator;
    QTranslator translator;

    int langIndx = gSettings.getLanguageIndex();
    if ((langIndx > 0) && (langIndx <= supportedLanguages.size())) {
        if (langIndx > 1) {
            // for all languages ​​except standard (German) and English
            // load English language first
            QString enlang = languageFilePrefix + supportedLanguages[0];
            if (en_translator.load(enlang)) {
                installTranslator(&en_translator);
            }
        }
        QString lang = languageFilePrefix + supportedLanguages[langIndx - 1];
        if (translator.load(lang)) {
            installTranslator(&translator);
        }
    }


